# Maximum area of a polygon inscribed in a complex triangle?

Tags: area, applications

Let $T$ be an acute triangle. Inscribe a pair $R,S$ of rectangles in $T$ as shown :

[image]

Let $A(x)$ denote area of polygon $X$ find the maximum value (or show that no maximum exists), of $\frac{A(R)+A(S)}{A(T)}$ where $T$ ranges over all triangles and $R,S$ overall rectangles as above .

Comment: I tried assuming sides of the rectangles inside and deriving an equation in terms of 4 unknown variables but couldn't proceed further . Also is there approach by integration possible ?

Comment: Fix the position of the left and right verts of the triangle at $(\pm 1, 0)$, and let the position of the top vert be $(a, 0)$. Then when you know the $x$-coordinate, $p$ of the bottom right vert of $R$, you can find the coords of its top right vert. Similarly, given that data, and the $x$-coordinate, $q$, of the bottom right corner of $S$, you can find the coord of its top right vert. Now compute the areas of $R$ and $S$, and maximize their sum as a function of $p$ and $q$. (The denominator, $A(T)$, is the constant $a$, so you can ignore it.) The domain is $0 \le p \le 1; 0 \le q \le p$.

Comment: @JohnHughes why did you fix $(\pm 1,0)$ as the vertices we don't know anything about the base length right?

Comment: I *chose* my units of measurement so that the base of the triangle happens to have length exactly two. :)  Alternatively, you can observe that if you scale the problem up or down by some amount, $c$, the areas in the numerator and denominator *both* scale by $c^2$, so that the ratio remains constant. So you can just scale your original problem until the width of the base happens to be 2 in whatever units you're using. In fact, the ratio is also invariant if you only scale in $y$, but that takes a tiny bit more reasoning to see. But once you buy it, you can assume the top point is $(0,1)$, too!

Comment: BTW, In my first comment, I wrote $(a,0)$ for the top vert, but should have said $(0, a)$. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sides as below shown below [image]

As in the figure

$\frac{A(S)+A(R)}{A(T)} = \frac{ay+bz}{\frac{hx}{2}}$

Where $h=a+b+c$ the altitude of $T$.
By similar triangles we have,

$\frac{x}{h}=\frac{y}{b+c}=\frac{z}{c}$

So 
$\frac{A(S)+A(R)}{A(T)} =\frac{2}{h^{2}} (ab+ac+ bc)$

we need to maximise $(ab+bc+ca)$ subject to $a+b+c=h$

One way to do this is to fix $a$ so that $b+c=h-a$

Then , $(ab+bc+ca+)=a(h-a)+bc$

$bc$ is maximised when $b=c$ we now wish to maximise $2ab+b^{2}$ subject to $a+2b=h$ .This is a straightforward calculus problem giving $a=b=c=\frac{1}{3}$

Hence the maximum ratio is $\frac{2}{3}$ ie: independant of $T$.